# What is and What is the biggest difference between Legacy JavaScript and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, legacy

I am looking at various practise differences between JavaScript and jQuery, at this site, and I stumbled upon something which I didn`t know about until now, called Legacy JavaScript at this link: 
http://alittlecode.com/comparing-scripts-in-jquery-and-javascript-a-comparison-by-jeffrey-way/

Selecting Elements
jQuery

```
$('#container');
```

JavaScript

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
```

Legacy JavaScript

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
```

What is it, what is more modern, what is really the deal here? Thanks :

Comment: Legacy just means 'old and outdated'.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if all you want is an element with a specific id, using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) is [**much faster**](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/23)

Comment: Note: JavaScript does not define any of those methods. They are part of the Web Platform API. Using the term "legacy JavaScript" in this context is misleading.

Comment: Just keep in mind what browsers are you targeting - http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector. Also I would not call it "legacy javascript". It's definitely connected with DOM and DOM have nothing to do with JavaScript...

Answer (score 2):

The `querySelector()` is a part of a new Selectors API. It is far more flexible and powerful than simple `getElementById()`.

Just look at the example in the [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/):

**Using old getElementById():**

```
var table = document.getElementById("score");
var groups = table.tBodies;
var rows = null;
var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  rows = groups[i].rows;
  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    cells.push(rows[j].cells[1]);
  }
}
```

**Using querySelector():**

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#score>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)");
```

From this example alone you can see, that those two methods are not equal in terms of functionality.

Additionally, note that neither of those is a part of Java Script language itself, but rather browser's DOM API.